# From where does fork() execute inside a loop?

Tags: c, linux, fork

Consider the below code, where will the program start executing after the fork() inside the for loop ? I'm not able to understand the output.

```
 #include <stdio.h>                                                                                 
 #include <sys/types.h>                                                                             

 int parent_code() {                                                                                
     printf("[%d] Parent\n",getpid());                                                                
 }                                                                                                  

 int child_code() {                                                                                 
     printf("[%d] Child\n",getpid());                                                                 
 }                                                                                                  

 int main() {                                                                                       
     int i;                                                                                           
     pid_t pid;                                                                                       

     for(i=0;i<4;i++) {                                                                               
         pid = fork();                                                                                  
         if(pid == 0) {                                                                                 
             child_code();                                                                                
         } else {                                                                                       
             parent_code();                                                                               
             waitpid(pid,&i,0);                                                                           
         }                                                                                              
     }                                                                                                
}
```

Output :

```
[4896] Parent
[4897] Child
[4897] Parent
[4898] Child
[4898] Parent
[4899] Child
[4899] Parent
[4900] Child
[4898] Parent
[4901] Child
[4897] Parent
[4902] Child
[4902] Parent
[4903] Child
[4897] Parent
[4904] Child
[4896] Parent
[4905] Child
[4905] Parent
[4906] Child
[4906] Parent
[4907] Child
[4905] Parent
[4908] Child
[4896] Parent
[4909] Child
[4909] Parent
[4910] Child
[4896] Parent
[4911] Child
```

### Update

1. Where does the child program starts its execution from ?
2. Won't there be a fork bomb (child again invoking fork) if it starts from the top ? So in this program I'm expecting the child process to start its execution from the line with `if(pid == 0) {`, I want only one parent process and 4 child process. Where have I gone wrong in doing that ?

Comment: What about it don't you understand? When `fork()` is called, a an entire child process is created as an exact copy of the parent process and execution then continues simultaneously in both processes (except the child "knows" it's a child because `fork()` returns `0` instead of a pid value.

Comment: @dai where does the child process starts its execution from ?

Comment: the child starts its' execution at the end of the fork() call, I.E. immediately after the point in the code at: pid = fork();.  so the child(and the parent) continue execution at the assignment of the variable pid.  The next line: if(pid == 0) {  is where  the parent/child determine if they are executing as the parent or the child.  Since this is in a loop, it happens over and over in both the parent and the child(as parent for the next child.  the use of the line just slows down the parent.

Comment: the fork'd process gets a copy of the current data, so every process soon exits the outer loop.  Even so, many processes are generated via the fork() in this loop.  That is why there is a limited number of processes generated and not an infinite number of processes.  Note: only 4 of those 'parent' messages are from the original parent.  All the other 'parent' messages are from child processes as they act as a parent in their respective loops  Each successive child inherients a larger value of 'i' until the tail child process never goes around the loop again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to understand the `fork` system call is to view it as a function that **returns twice**. It returns once in the parent, like a normal function does and again in a new process. 
Both processes continue where `fork` "returned".

> I want only one parent process and 4 child process. Where have I gone
>   wrong in doing that

Think of the first child process. It calls `child_code()` and then **it itself forks**. So the children fork too if they can go through the loop. An easy way to prevent that would be to call `break` just after `child_code`.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically making a tree.
Example on max 2:

```
Process
0       Parent                 Parent
1             Child Parent
2                         Child
3                                    Child Parent
4                                                Child
```